# Is it right to say, "I have wanted to make this cake since so long"

Tags: sentence-construction

Say you make a cake after having wanted to make it for a long time. You say, "I finally got around to making this cake." and then you say "**I have wanted to make this cake since/for so long.**" Has the sentence in boldface been constructed correctly? What about, "I have been wanting to make this cake for so long?"

Comment: Doesn't 'have wanted' imply that I still want to bake the cake. In the question I asked, I have already baked the cake. So shouldn't I say, "I had wanted to make this  cake for so long"?

Comment: Not necessarily. You could be in the process of making the cake, or you could be serving it to someone... If you're showing someone photos of the cake three weeks later, "had" would be better, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Since" really needs a more specific time frame.

> I have wanted to make this cake since last year/week/month.
>   I have wanted to make this cake since Monday/January/2005.

If you want to use something less specific like "so long", you need to use "for".

> I have wanted to make this cake for so long.
>   I have wanted to make this cake for weeks/months/years.

You might also consider the construction:

> I've been wanting to make this cake since/for...

Comment: So there is nothing wrong with the 'I have wanted' part of the sentence, right.

Comment: Nope. Just another option.